# Enforce REST route service module version

Tags: here-api

I'm using the here REST routing api (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/api-reference.html) and I noticed that the reponses I get for the same request are sometimes different. I looked into the JSON reponse and I noticed that the mapVersion, moduleVersion and interfaceVersion were different.

I looked into the documentation to find a way to specify the mapVersion/moduleVersion/interfaceVersion I want but I could not find any.

Is there a way to be sure that subsequent calls to the routing api will be performed with the same server or at least the same data and algorithm ?

Example of request for wich I got a different response with subsequent calls :

```
Request :
    http://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?&mode=shortest;car;traffic:disabled&representation=display&&app_id=<APPID>&app_code=<APPCODE>&waypoint0=geo!48.7536638,-3.4404475&waypoint1=geo!48.7532906,-3.4402628&waypoint2=geo!48.7529834,-3.4415456&waypoint3=geo!48.7526572,-3.4413922&waypoint4=geo!48.7532489,-3.4399076&waypoint5=geo!48.7536333,-3.43932

Response1 :
    {"response":{"metaInfo":{"timestamp":"2017-01-20T10:56:55Z","mapVersion":"8.30.64.152","moduleVersion":"7.2.74.0-71276","interfaceVersion":"2.6.25"},"route": <...>

Reponse2:
    {"response":{"metaInfo":{"timestamp":"2017-01-20T10:58:38Z","mapVersion":"8.30.67.153","moduleVersion":"7.2.201703-97140","interfaceVersion":"2.6.29"},"route":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here support answer :

> The issue with different versions is not seen now, it might have been
>   only a temporary one. It could be a very unlikely coincidence that you
>   had noticed this when our services in the servers were being updated.
>
> Please understand that the Map Data used by the different services are
>   updates on a weekly/biweekly basis and an updated version of the
>   service itself is released to the servers on a monthly basis. So there
>   could be changes in these versions from time to time, but there is no
>   options to use a specific map version or module version for your
>   request.
>
> But ideally you should not see a difference in the main route
>   response parameters for the same routing request, unless there is a
>   considerable map data change for these regions.

Comment: I suppose the last sentence is a typo, and should read "But ideally you should **not** see a difference in the main route response parameters...", doesn't it?